# Sequence ajax requests in redux observables based on response of first, And individually handle error and dispatch actions

Tags: react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to sequence two ajax requests in redux-observables, and second request will be based on response of first, And i individually want to dispatch response or error of both requests.

Using concat to process one request after another but i am stuck on how to use response of first one into second request. If i chain using two switchMap then  through result selector i will get inner and outer observables but i am not getting how to dispatch action after first request.

```
export const deleteSettingsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('DELETE_SETTINGSDATA'),
    switchMap(action$ => concat(
        ajax.ajaxDelete(`${action$.payload.api}/${action$.payload.id}`)
            .pipe(
                map(r => ({ type: 'DELETE_SUCCESS', payload: r })),
                catchError(e => of({ type: 'DELETE_ERROR' }))
            ),
        ajax.get(`${action$.payload.api}?page=${action$.payload.query.page}&limit=${action$.payload.query.limit}`)
            .pipe(
                map(r => ({
                    type: action$.payload.getPaginationAction,
                    payload: {
                        data: r.response.docs,
                        page: r.response.page,
                        totalPages: r.response.totalPages,
                        limit: r.response.limit,
                        totalDocs: r.response.totalDocs
                    }
                })),
                catchError(e => of({ type: 'FETCH_ERROR' }))
            ),
        of({ type: 'SET_DIMMER_FALSE' }).pipe(delay(250)),
        of({ type: 'RESET_ERRORS' }).pipe(delay(1500)),
    )
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `concatMap` for the second ajax request, in pseudo code:

```
export const deleteSettingsEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('DELETE_SETTINGSDATA'),
    switchMap(action$ => ajax.ajaxDelete(...)),
    concatMap(result => ajax.get(...))
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm just scratching the surface of rxjs.

Comment: you're welcome! If you find the answer usefull , vote or mark the answer as the solution, please.

Comment: I would definitely like to, but i have just started to ask questions on stackoverflow and i don't have enough reputation to upvote.